# Point cPanel subdomain to CodeIgniter controller

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

I have a CodeIgniter controller which looks like this:

```
mysite.com/controller
```

What I want to do is to be able to call this controller from a subdomain, e.g.:

```
subdomain.mysite.com
```

When I create a subdomain through cPanel, it creates the folder `subdomain` to the root of my site and it cannot point to the CI controller instead.

I tried with different `.htaccess` combinations found here on SO and other sites, with no luck.

I also read that there is the option of creating 2 separate CI applications, but I would not like to do that.

My .htaccess currently has options only for removing `index.php` from url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `base_url` in `application/config/config.php` to this subdomain an then set your `default_controller` in `application/config/routes.php`.

Comment: But I do not want this controller to be the default. It is just a controller, which the subdomain must point to.

Comment: Ah ok, i see what you want to do. Maybe [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/) is what you need.